# calling sock_sendmsg in kernel module returns (-1) permission denied

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel

I am working on a driver and I need to send UDP packets from the kernel.  When I run it in a VM, everything is fine and the packet is sent out.  However, when I run it directly on hardware sock_sendmsg() returns -1.

I am running on Kali Linux with kernel version 4.13.0-kali1-amd64 in both environments.  They were built from Kali Linux 2017.2 and all packages were up to date.

sockDenied.c:

```
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/version.h>


#include <linux/uaccess.h>        // for get_fs, get_ds, set_fs
#include <linux/inet.h>           // for in4_pton
#include <net/sock.h>             // for IPPROTO_IP, SOCK_DGRAM, AF_INET
#include <linux/net.h>            // for sock_create, sock_alloc_file


MODULE_AUTHOR("helpme");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("sock_sendmsg recieving permission denied");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Global Variables
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static mm_segment_t _oldfs;

int my_inet_pton(int af, const char *src, void *dst) {
    printk("In %s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (AF_INET == af) {
        return in4_pton(src, strlen(src), (u8*) dst, '\0', NULL);
    } else if (AF_INET6 == af) {
        return in6_pton(src, strlen(src), (u8*) dst, '\0', NULL);
    } else {
        printk("uknown af value = %d", af);
        return -1;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//      Static Functions : UDP
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static int __init sockdenied_init(void) {    
    int retval = 0;
    struct msghdr msg = {};
    struct iovec iov = {};
    char data[2] = {0x01, 0x02};
    static struct sockaddr_in txaddr = {};

    struct socket* sock = NULL;
    struct file* fp = NULL;
    u32 dstip;

    _oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

    retval = my_inet_pton(AF_INET, "1.1.1.1", &dstip);

    retval = sock_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP, &sock);
    fp = sock_alloc_file(sock, 0, NULL);

    txaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    txaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = dstip;
    txaddr.sin_port = htons(50000);

    iov.iov_base = data;
    iov.iov_len = 2;

    iov_iter_init(&msg.msg_iter, READ, &iov, 1, 1);

    msg.msg_flags = 0;
    msg.msg_name = &(txaddr);
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
    msg.msg_control = NULL;
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;

    retval = sock_sendmsg(sock, &msg);

    printk(KERN_INFO"sock_sendmsg returned: %d", retval);

    sock_release(sock);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit sockdenied_exit(void) {

    set_fs(_oldfs);

    return;
}

module_init(sockdenied_init);
module_exit(sockdenied_exit);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m+=sockDenied.o
MY_CFLAGS+= -g -DDEBUG
ccflags-y+= ${MY_CFLAGS}
CC += ${MY_CFLAGS}

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD)  modules
    EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(MY_CFLAGS)"
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

Why am I recieving -EPERM? How can my module not have permssion do send the UDP packet?  Why does a VM behave differently.

Comment: What did returned the function `my_inet_pton` and `sock_create`?

Comment: sock_create returns 0 and my_inet_pton returns 1

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I unknowingly had an outbound IP tables rule that was blocking my traffic. I removed the rule and the issue was resolved.